# FastAPI , ошибка запроса PUT

Tags: python, fastapi

Всем здравствуйте.
Появляется ошибка 500 при изменении данных, запроc PUT. причем код работает. при получении списка видно что изменения есть. все остальное работает. спасибо заранее.

```
import logging  
import uvicorn  
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel  

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)  
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)     

app = FastAPI()

class User(BaseModel):     
    id: int
    name: str
    email: str  
    password: str

class UserInput(BaseModel):     
    name: str
    email: str  
    password: str

users = [] 

@app.get("/users/")
async def get_users():    # Маршрут для получения списка задач (метод GET).
    logger.info('Отработан GET запрос на получение списка пользователей.')
    return users

@app.get("/users/{id}")
async def read_user(id: int):
    if len(users)<id:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    logger.info('Отработан GET запрос на получение одного пользователя.')   
    return users[id-1]

@app.post("/users/", response_model=list[User])   # Маршрут для добавления нового пользователя (метод POST)
async def new_user(user: UserInput):
    user = User(
            id=len(users) + 1,
            name=user.name,
            email=user.email,
            password=user.password
            )
    users.append(user)
    logger.info('Отработан POST запрос. Пользователь успешно добавлен.')
    return users
 
@app.put("/users/{id}", response_model=UserInput)
async def update_user(id: int, new_user: UserInput):
    #a = len(users)
    #print(len(users) , id)
    #logger.info('Длина списка пользователей {a}. id ={id}.')
    if len(users)<id:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    for user in users:
        if user.id == id:
            user.name = new_user.name
            user.email = new_user.email
            user.password = new_user.password
            return f'Пользователь {id} изменен'          
    logger.info('Отработан PUT запрос на изменение пользователя {id}.')  
    
@app.delete("/users/{id}", response_model=str)
async def delete_task(id: int): # , new_user: UserInput
    if len(users)<id:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    for user in users:
        if user.id == id:
            users.remove(user)
            return f'Пользователь {id} удален'   
    logger.info('Отработан DELETE запрос на удаление пользователя {id}.') 



"""основа"""
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    uvicorn.run("task_sem5:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reload=True)
```

---

пишу в VSCode. В терминале такое:

```
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 1 validation errors:
  {'type': 'model_attributes_type', 'loc': ('response',), 'msg': 'Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from', 'input': 'Пользователь 3 изменен', 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/model_attributes_type'}
```

Answer (score 1):

В качестве возвращаемого значения

```
@app.put("/users/{id}", response_model=UserInput)
```

явно указан UserInput

```
class UserInput(BaseModel):     
    name: str
    email: str  
    password: str
```

Однако возвращается просто строка `f'Пользователь {id} изменен'`

В связи с этим происходит ошибка:

```
'Input should be a valid dictionary or object to extract fields from'
'input': 'Пользователь 3 изменен'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Это осталось от извращенчеств.  забыл удалить. что есть "return f'Пользователь {id} изменен'  ", что нет - результат одинаковый

Comment: интересует это - 'type': 'model_attributes_type'ю

Comment: где я накосячил?)

Comment: @rivitch, ты указал что вернешь UserInput - а его не возвращаешь. Об этом и ошибка

Comment: переделал. но не понял. пятихатка исчезла)

'''
@app.put("/users/{id}", response_model=UserInput)
def edit_task(id: int, new_user: UserInput):
    for user in users:
        if user.id == id:
            user.name = new_user.name
            user.email = new_user.email
            user.password = new_user.password
            return user
        logger.info(f'Отработан PUT запрос на изменение пользователя {id}.')
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Task not found")
'''

Comment: спасибо за участие)

Comment: кстати, как так красиво в коментах оформлять код? тут никаких кнопов. я тут недавно, не разобрался еще)

Comment: @rivitch "никаких кнопов": https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxtvi.png Ну и см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: @insolor

'
спасибо. 
почитаю
'

не сработало...(

Comment: @rivitch [А почему у меня не подсвечивается код в комментариях?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3286/186999)

Comment: 'спасибо. был перенос строки'

Comment: @Grundy  поглядел.'спасибо. был перенос строки после кавычек'.не работает, пробелов нет

Comment: '@app.put("/users/{id}", response_model=UserInput) def edit_task(id: int, new_user: UserInput): for user in users: if user.id == id: user.name = new_user.name user.email = new_user.email user.password = new_user.password return user logger.info(f'Отработан PUT запрос на изменение пользователя {id}.') raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Task not found")'

Comment: @rivitch ты ставишь не те кавычки - это раз. комментарии не предназначены, чтобы в них код многострочный вставляли - это два

Comment: @Grundy , у тебя же получилось так откомментировать мой вопрос. У меня получилось, когда вопрос задавал. Выходит, в комментах к комментам нельзя код украсивничать? Жаль..

Comment: "спасибо. проверка других кавычек"и одна строка не работает(

Comment: @rivitch кавычки обратные `\`` должны быть